# Could we construct an inverse transform for the equivalence $D^b(X)\to D^b(M)$ between a K3 surface and its moduli space of semistable sheaves?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, derived-categories, k3-surfaces

Let $X$ be a K3 surface and fix an ample line bundle on $X$. Let $v\in \widetilde{H}(X,\mathbb{Z})$ be a Mukai vector and $M(v)$ be the moduli space of semi-stable coherent sheaves on $X$ with Mukai vector $v$. Under certain conditions on $v$, we could show that $M(v)$ is a fine moduli space and parametrizes only stable sheaves and in addition dim$M(v)=2$. As a result there exists a universal sheaf $\mathcal{E}$ on $X\times M(v)$. Let $M\subset M(v)$ be a connected component. Then we have the following theorem of Mukai.

> > Under above assumptions, the integral transform
> >     $$
> > \Phi_{\mathcal{E}}:D^b(X)\to D^b(M)
> > $$
> >     gives an equivalence of trangulated categories, where $D^b(-)$ denotes the bounded derived category of coherent sheaves. See [Huybrechts](http://www.oxfordscholarship.com/view/10.1093/acprof:oso/9780199296866.001.0001/acprof-9780199296866) Section 10.3 for details.

The proof of above theorem in [Huybrechts](http://www.oxfordscholarship.com/view/10.1093/acprof:oso/9780199296866.001.0001/acprof-9780199296866) depends on the general criterion of equivalence of integral transforms rather than giving an inverse functor. Nevertheless, in the analogue theorem for abelian varieties, an inverse functor could be given.

> > My question is: for a K3 surface $X$, could we construct an inverse functor for $\Phi_{\mathcal{E}}$ and realize it as a integral transform?

Comment: Orlov's theorem states that any exact fully faithful functor between $D^b Coh$ of smooth projective varieties can be realised as an integral transform, at least if you allow arbitrary objects of $D^b(X × Y)$ as integral kernels. That certainly applies to your case, so yes, the inverse functor is an integral transform. An inverse functor is in particular right adjoint, and a right adjoint to an integral transform can be realised as an integral transform by the dual sheaf, considered as an object of $D^b(M × X)$ and dualized in that category.

Comment: @AntonFetisov I see, it's so obvious.